# What's the function of looper for constructor of Handler？

Tags: android, android-handler, android-looper

I am confused on the function of `Looper` in the `Handler`.

I have some code like this:

**snippet1:**

```
mThread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(tag, "thread 1 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
        //if(null == Looper.myLooper()) {// This is redundant.
            //Looper.prepare();
        //}
        Log.d(tag, "thread 2 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
        mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.d(tag, "thread 3 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            }
        };
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        //Looper.loop(); // This is redundant since mHandler has a mainLooper, and loop in main thread.
    }
};
```

**snippet2:**

```
mThread = new Thread(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.d(tag, "thread 1 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
        if(null == Looper.myLooper()) {
            Looper.prepare();
        }
        Log.d(tag, "thread 2 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
        mHandler = new Handler(){
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                Log.d(tag, "thread 3 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread());
            }
        };
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        Looper.loop();
    }
};
```

With different `Looper` passed to the Handler, I got different output from `handleMessage`, **the snippet1 log "thread 3" output main thread, the snippet2 log "thread 3" output child thread**, so I am confused on the function of `Looper` passed to `Handler`, **can it switch the thread where to handle the method `handlerMessage`**. I haven't found any clue in the `Handler` source.

Anyone can help me out, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is the best blog on this
http://techtej.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html

Comment: are you asking what a looper is?

Comment: @pskink The code used the passed looper and looper's messagequeue, but how it swith the thread?

Comment: @TimCastelijns No, I want to know how it switch the thread.

Comment: @pskink I just want to know how it switch the thread, but I sure will not use handler and looper like the snippet above.

Comment: @pskink because the output of Log.d(tag, "thread 3 current thread:" + Thread.currentThread()); is different by snippet1 and snippet2

Comment: "I want to know how it switch the thread" - so you don't know what a looper is?

Comment: @TimCastelijns All I know is that looper is a loop that get message from messagequeue and dispatch to handler.

Comment: @pskink Yes, I know this, maybe my express is not clear, what I am confused is that, the `new Handler()` use the current `Thread`'s `Looper`, and the messeage is send to the `Looper`'s messagequeue, and the handler is attached to the thread, but the hanldeMessage is running on UI thread, I will check the `HandlerThread`.

Comment: @pskink My fault, the `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` is redundant for snippet1